# next image not shown on small screens

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, next-images

I'm having a problem with the next image component, some images are not shown on mobile but on large screens they are. If I manually change browser width they won't disappear.

For example

```js
<Image src="/images/header-image.svg" width="676px" height="463px" />
```

I tried without width and height and with layout fill but the problem is the same, and if the layout is responsive image is not showing at all screen sizes.